# Resizing a circle - Where is the bug sitting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, geometry

I have the following code, the circle doesn't resize:

### HTML

```
<div onMouseOver="mainOver();" onMouseOut="mainOut();" id="c"></div>
```

### JavaScript / jQuery

```
function mainIn()
{
    $('#c').animate({
        border-radius: '100',
        webkit-border-radius: '100',
        moz-border-radius: '100',
        width: '200',
        height: '200',
        margin-left: '-100',
        margin-top: '-100'
    });
}

function mainOut()
{
    $('#c').animate({
        border-radius: '50',
        webkit-border-radius: '50',
        moz-border-radius: '50',
        width: '100',
        height: '100',
        margin-left: '-50',
        margin-top: '-50'
    });
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9j795/1)

### The problem

- The circle does nothing, even when hovered.

Comment: Hm, you should tell us what's not working correctly?

Comment: It's not resizing? I thought that it was quite obvious.. If wasn't just write...

Comment: Ok I found the 7th version and it's working, but the animation is bit weird.. Any tweak?

Comment: Links to other sites should be supplemental. Please post the relevant code here so future readers are ensured the ability to benefit from this question.

Comment: I've edited your question to corrospond with the expected format for questions in this site, please follow it (paste code here, not in links, post an example, clearly specify the problem). Happy questioning :)

Comment: @David Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Don't overwrite your question with an *"it works"* message. If there's an answer that helped you solve the problem, click the large checkmark to the left of it.

Comment: Lucky for you I saved a copy. Don't override your question, simply accept a correct answer to mark it as closed. Think of future developers having problems similar to yours and wanting to know what you had wrong and how you corrected it.

Comment: @Rikudo I edited it more and I have written the answer + tweaked the question edited by Jim :)

Comment: @DavidDebnar: I think you may be missing the basic idea behind StackOverflow. Question is at the top, and answers are in the "Answers" section below. Please don't post the solution in your question. You can ask the user with the "accepted" answer to post some additional detail if you wish, or you can post an answer yourself if you've changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you didn't include jQuery in your jsfiddle
2. Use `border-radius:50%` to make a square circle in **anysize**
3. Use jQuery to bind events, it's easier!
4. Animation need timing and callback function

Look at fixed code:

```
$('#c').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        width: 200,
        height:200,
        'margin-left':'-100px',
        'margin-top':'-100px'
    }, 500, function(){});
},function(){
    $(this).animate({
        width: 100,
        height:100,
        'margin-left':'-50px',
        'margin-top':'-50px'
    }, 500, function(){});
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen/9j795/16/**

Comment: Wow..Dude you helped me more times.. I need to thank you VERY much :).. This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: no problem. Please choose the answer as correct answer if it's your question answer. ;)

Comment: +1 mainly for the border-radius: 50%. Other people had made most of the other comments but animating the border-radius up and down seemed to strangely fail but this does the job perfectly. :)

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues in your code:

### You're using jQuery, so use it's handlers.

You should instead using the handlers in jQuery, such as [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to handle the mouse over and mouse out.

### There are no dashes in JavaScript properties

You can't do things like `margin-top: "-50px"` let alone `margin  -  top: "-50px"`, instead, you should be using **[camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)** `marginTop: "-50px"` or to stringify your properties: `"margin-top": "-50px"`.

### Vendor prefixes are not needed

jQuery automatically handles the specific browser correct version. No need to animate `-webkit-border-radius` and the such.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kZTBC/)**.

Answer (score 2):

Don't add `javascript:` to `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut`. Just `mainOver()` and `mainOut()` is all you need.

EDIT: Also, you wrote `mainOver()` in one place, and `mainIn()` in the other.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few things:

1. `border-radius` is interpreted as `border - radius`. In jQuery, the properties camel case: `borderRadius`.
2. Don't do `onmouseover`, etc. jQuery provides this functionality.
3. No need to animate `-webkit-...`, etc. jQuery should take care of this.

See this code for the fixes: http://jsfiddle.net/9j795/7/

Comment: For me (in FF) that version of the code does strange things with going via squares in between rather than just being a smoothly expanding circle...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/9j795/19/ Is that fiddle with a bit of a slowdown. It seems that at the beginning of the animation it loses the curved corners and becomes a square and then gradually animates the curvy corners in again... It looks like it may be a jquery bug rather than anything else...

Comment: Looks like @Mohsen has fixed that issue by using 50% for the corner radius, getting rid of the need to animate it at all.